# CSS - floating divs align left

Tags: css, alignment

I have 6 floating divs (align to left) on a page. These divs has 2 different widths (depending the image () ). One div has 295px and the another has 216px. The height is calculated automatically by HTML. The container has 1050px, so in one "line" of the container I can insert 3 divs, and the another 3 on the second "line".

The CSS rule is working, all divs are floating to the left, each div has 20px margin, but the problem is the alignment of them.  I want to align these divs proportional. At the moment if some pictures has different heights, on the second "line" are some blank spaces (because the height of the pictures above).

I want something to float these divs on the Y coordinate (proportional).

Look at this pictures:
[image]

Comment: You mean y-alignment between lines equally taking into account the max height of the larger picture in the above line?

Comment: You should use `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a jsfiddle for people to play with.

But, you will probably want to make a container div for each row. This encapsulates the 3 inner divs, being as high as them and allowing the next container to fit nicely underneath

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TJxmT/

Comment: extra markup, not always the best solution IMHO ... See my answer you can do it using CSS only

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a min-height at the floating divs solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery plugin called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to fix that layout... You will be surprised!

EDIT:

You can always clear the 1st item in the row and every third item using css :

```
li:nth-child(3n+4) { clear:left; }
```

Comment: It's quite amazing, but I have 2 different classes for divs.

Comment: Give them an extra class for both ... for example : class="class-one block" and class="class-two block" ... we are using the class "block" here as a common class

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a `clear: both;` on every first div of a new line?

Comment: I updated the fiddle from user 1538100 with my sugestion. Seems to work just fine, without the extra containers... Perhaps i misunderstood the question. http://jsfiddle.net/TJxmT/1/